# How to select multiple rows in a pandas column to create a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe and there are some columns that I want to keep in terms of location and others I do not.

I know that when selecting a specific value in a column to get a row I can use:

```
x = df[df['location']=='Aberdeen']
```

However, how can I do it for many locations without having to do them individually and then concatenate?

This is what Ive tried:

```
x = df[[df['location']=='Aberdeen' & 'Glasgow' & 'London']]
```

But I am receiving a:

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

I know there must be a super simple solution to this but I haven't figured it out, please help.

Comment: `df[df["location"].isin(["Aberdeen", "Glasgow", "London"])]` might do the trick

Comment: @AngusWilliams - Yes, you are right.

Comment: Initially typed up as an answer but it's been marked as a dupe.

Comment: @AngusWilliams Thank you! I will use that. Did not realise it was a duplicate because I didn't even know how to structure the title Question. I'll be checking that out and shutting this one down. Thanks again all.